# Xamarin Forms FindByName always returns null

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I have a ContentPage that is bound to a viewmodel. Still, at one point, I need to access a Picker inside a StackLayout which in turn is in a Syncfusion ListViewItem. The XAML is pretty straightforward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:sf="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PerformanceTM.Views.NewCircuitView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <sf:SfListView x:Name="ExerciseList" ItemsSource="{Binding Exercises}" DragStartMode="OnHold">
                <sf:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Picker Title="Kategorie" x:Name="CategoryPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference ExerciseList}, Path=BindingContext.ExerciseCategories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding Category}" SelectedIndexChanged="CategoryChanged"/>
                                <Picker Title="Übung" x:Name="ExerciseNamePicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedIndexChanged="ExerciseSelected"/>
                                <Button Text="..." Clicked="ConfigureSetsClicked"/>
                                <Button Text="(-)" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sf:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </sf:SfListView>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="(+) Übung" Command="{Binding AddExerciseCommand}"/>
            <Button Text="Ok" Command="{Binding ApplyChangesCommand}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

As you can see, both Pickers in the ViewCell have x:Name assigned to them. When I select a value in the ExerciseCategoryPicker, I load and assign new values to to ExerciseNamePicker in Code behind, like so:

```
    private async void CategoryChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = sender as Picker;
        var stackLayout = picker.Parent as StackLayout;
        ListViewItem listViewItem = stackLayout.Parent as ListViewItem;

        var ex = picker.BindingContext as Exercise;
        if (ex is null)
            return;

        ex.Category = picker.SelectedItem as ExerciseCategory;

        var apiService = new ApiServices();
        var exsForCategory = await apiService.GetExercisesForCategory(ex.Category.Name);

        Picker exnp = stackLayout.FindByName<Picker>("ExerciseNamePicker");
        if (exnp is null)
            exnp = stackLayout.Children.OfType<Picker>().Where(x => x.Title == "Übung").FirstOrDefault();

        exnp.ItemsSource = exsForCategory;
        if (exsForCategory.Count > 0)
            exnp.SelectedItem = exsForCategory.FirstOrDefault();

        var bc = this.BindingContext as NewCircuitViewModel;
        bc.ExercisePairing.Descriptor = bc.ExercisePairing.UpdateDescriptor();
    }

private void ExerciseSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var picker = (sender as Picker);
            var stackLayout = picker.Parent as StackLayout;
            var vc = picker.Parent.Parent as Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ListViewItem;
            var ex = vc.BindingContext as Exercise;
            var se = picker.ItemsSource[picker.SelectedIndex] as Exercise;

            var exnp = stackLayout.FindByName("CategoryPicker") as Picker;
            if (exnp is null)
                exnp = stackLayout.Children.OfType<Picker>().Where(x => x.Title == "Kategorie").FirstOrDefault();

            var ec = exnp.SelectedItem as ExerciseCategory;

            ex.Category = ec;
            ex.Name = se.Name;
            ex.Id = se.Id;
            ex.Description = se.Description;
            ex.VideoUrl = se.VideoUrl;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now what happens is that FindByName() returns null in each situation. Oddly enough, when I debug and inspect the Children of StackLayout just before calling FindByName, it does contain children with the appropriate IDs (i.e., the x:Name). When I access them via get, I get the GUID (this somehow confuses me, as I thought there should only be a GUID in the first place, but well).

I have found a workaround by just selecting the element by Title, but this is a rather strange behaviour, especially considering that this has worked in the past. Only change I made since then was the integration of the SyncFusion ListView. Could that be an issue? Has anyone experienced this and/or can provide more insight?

PS: I have gone through all the "usual" fixes such as deleting the .v, bin and obj folders...

Comment: It is not a good design to invoke `FindByName` in ListView . You would better use DataBinding .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the children element of **SfListView.ItemTemplate** using behavior for the parent element of the ItemTemplate. Please refer the following code snippet for getting the named elements inside DataTemplate,

**Xaml**: Define Behavior for StackLayout

```
<sf:SfListView x:Name="ExerciseList" ItemsSource="{Binding Exercises}" DragStartMode="OnHold">
<sf:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout.Behaviors>
                    <local:Behavior/>
                </StackLayout.Behaviors>

                <Picker Title="Kategorie" x:Name="CategoryPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference ExerciseList}, Path=BindingContext.ExerciseCategories}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding Category}"/>
                <Picker Title="Übung" x:Name="ExerciseNamePicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Button Text="..." Clicked="ConfigureSetsClicked"/>
                <Button Text="(-)" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</sf:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**Behavior**: Get element using FindByElement. Trigger SelectedIndexChanged event for Picker.

```
public class Behavior : Behavior<StackLayout>
{
    Picker CategoryPicker;
    Picker ExerciseNamePicker;

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(StackLayout bindable)
    {
        CategoryPicker = bindable.FindByName<Picker>("CategoryPicker");
        ExerciseNamePicker = bindable.FindByName<Picker>("ExerciseNamePicker");

        CategoryPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += CategoryPicker_SelectedIndexChanged;
        ExerciseNamePicker.SelectedIndexChanged += ExerciseNamePicker_SelectedIndexChanged;

        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    }

    private void ExerciseNamePicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your logic here.
    }

    private void CategoryPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your logic here.
    }
}
```

You can also refer our online document regarding the same from the following link,
[Document](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11287/how-to-access-a-named-listview-inside-a-xaml-datatemplate-in-xamarin-forms-sflistview)

Comment: Thank you very much. In the end, I wound up replacing that code with by severely changing my model and creating a new viewmodel, as suggested by Lucas Zhang. I can't accept his answer, however, as simply pointing out bad coding style without offering anything constructive is not very helpful. Should I run into similar issues again, I will look int behaviours.